# Track the static OS changes on Linux (installed package version change etc.)

Tags: linux, monitoring

Is there a Linux way that can be used to track package version change, or any file change?

For my own purpose I'm looking for a tool that:

- takes in a saved status of the entire OS. And takes another state as an input and run comparison.
- expresses the state by files' checksum (and maybe the last update timestamp).

So e.g. if there's a file with the same name between the OS' state A and state B whose checksum is different, then I can say there was a change.

Just to say I've done some research already, I've found the following tools. AFAICT, they can be used to check any change while the tool keeps running. While I think it's useful (I'm listing below just for record), that's not enough for my usecase. I want to be able to compare with the pre-recorded state like mentioned above, which I couldn't figure out each one has an ability to do so.

- [Watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman)
- [CheckInstall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall)
- [PyInotify](https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify). This seems a different package from the previous one with the same name [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify).

Or else, I was going to write a script that returns a list of all files on a disk with absolute path, checksum and timestamp for the last update. But I don't want to reinvent anything that already exists.

Comment: For `/etc`, there's e.g. etckeeper. But that covers only that one directory with all its contents.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing Tripwire.